# Are the period of signal and its fourier coefficient the same?

Tags: fourier-series, fourier-transform

Are the period of signal and its fourier coefficient the same?i mean if the the period of $x[n]$ is $5$,will the period of its fourier coefficient ,$a_k$, also $5$? how to prove it?

Because the definition of a periodic is $x[n]=x[n+N]$,but if we do fourier series at the same time ,it will become $a_k=a_k \times e^{jwkN}$,and in this formula,$w=\frac{2 \pi}{N}$,so i it will become $a_k=a_k \times e^{j \pi k}$
,i can't know the period of $a_k$ from here.

Comment: Did you try a single sine wave signal first?

Comment: @Somos but if i do that,that maybe the exception,can we just use the definition to prove that?

Comment: Next try a finite linear combination of sine waves all with periods a sub-multiple (subharmonics) of a fundamental period.

Comment: @Somos I have proved it by definition,the answer is "yes",if $a_k$ is a periodic,its period must be equal to its inverse fourier coefficient $x[n]$

Comment: I don't understand your question. Can you give a simple example of what you are asking? I don't understand what a coefficient being periodic means. It is just a number. What is $x[n]$? What is $a_k$?

Comment: i mean if the the period of $x[n]$ is $5$,will the period of its fourier coefficient ,$a_k$, also $5$?

Comment: You have not given a single example of what you are asking about. Please do so.

Comment: no this question don't need any example,i think i don't understand why do you insist to have an example

Comment: ha,i don't give you what you want,and you give me a bad vote,ridiculous

Answer (score 0):

if $a_k$ is periodic,then $a_k=a_{k+p}$,$p$ is the period of $a_k$

by definition

$a_k=\frac{1}{N}\sum\limits_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-j\frac{2 \pi}{N}kn}$,and $a_{k+p}=\frac{1}{N}\sum\limits_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-j\frac{2 \pi}{N}(z-p)n}=\frac{1}{N}\sum\limits_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-j\frac{2 \pi}{N}zn}e^{j\frac{2 \pi}{N}pn}$,if $a_{k+p}$ wants to be equal to $a_k$,then $p$ must be equal to $N$,so that $e^{j\frac{2 \pi}{N}pn}=e^{j2 \pi n} = 1$.

$p$ must be equal to $N$.that is the period of the $a_k = $ the period of the $x[n]$